# Not able to understand Mapper and reducer of a hive query

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Could someone help me to understand how mapper and reducer are being created for the below query. Below mentioned is the query and result of the query.
I want to know :

1. Why it has Map1 and Map4 , why not Map2 and Map3
2. Why it has Reduce 2,3 not 1
3. Is there any way to improve the performance of the query?

   ```
   hive>
           > select agegroup , sum(safe_cnt),sum(unsafe_cnt) from
           > (
           > select case when b.age <= 25 then 'age25' when (b.age > 25 and b.age < 35) then 'age35'
           > when (b.age >= 35 and b.age < 45) then 'age45' else 'age50' end as agegroup ,
           >  a.safe_cnt, a.unsafe_cnt  from
           > (select cust_id, sum (case when place = 'safe' then 1 else 0 end) as safe_cnt, sum (case when place = 'unsafe' then 1 else 0 end) as unsafe_cnt from               directive_ana.sensor_main group by cust_id) a
           > left outer join directive_ana.cust_main b where a.cust_id = b.cust_id
           > ) e
           > group by agegroup ;
       Query ID = root_xxxxx_xxxxxXxxx_xxx_xxx_xxx
       Total jobs = 1
       Launching Job 1 out of 1
   ```

Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_147071xxxxx_xxx)

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 ..........   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Map 4 ..........   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 2 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 3 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 04/04  [==========================>>] 100%  ELAPSED TIME: 9.17 s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK
age25   8       7
age35   202     166
age45   194     163
age50   740     611
Time taken: 14.04 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Comment: This is output of tez engine for hive; not map-reduce based execution. Tez underlying principle is directed acyclic graphs which need a different analysis pattern than MR. So probably easy way will be to change `set hive.execution.engine=mr;` and then look into explain plan of hive query.

Comment: EXPLAIN works the same with MR and TEZ. The difference is in the way they allocate resources to Mappers and Containers *(and in the way they report their status & log stuff)*

Comment: So does that mean we have 2 mapper and 2 reducer??

Comment: @AmitSharma Based on your status overview, you have indeed 2 map stages and 2 reduce stages. I believe the number (roughly) indicates the order in which the data goes through the stages.